# Apache Kafka does not send the entire message (cuts at character 4092)

Tags: linux, apache-kafka, bigdata

I´m testing Kafa pasting a Json in a console producer. In the console consumer appears the message interrupted at the character no. 4092.

Only if I send the message with a "cat" of the file it works:

```
> cat ~/myfile | bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
```

I have already created the topic, and my conf files are as default

Comment: Maybe a bash limitation not being able to pipe lines longer than 4K?

Comment: If I send the messages via flume same happens. Also pasting the message in a new gedit, is all pasted.

Comment: Kafka has a broker/topic setting for `max.message.bytes` but default is 1 MB. Maybe double check if this parameter got changed.

Comment: It is by default. Anyway I edit the property in server.properties and nothing changed. The issue is that is working with the "cat file" so I think configuration is not the problem. If I send plain text it only allows 4096 characters

Comment: I just realized that the messages received from flume has a serializer with the property "agent.sources.r1.deserializer.maxLineLength = 4096"  I changed the value and now it works. But I don´t still know why If I write in the console producer a message larger than 4096 characters is cut in the consumer

Comment: No idea. Internally, `java.io.BufferedReader#readlLine()` is used -- there should be no such limitation. Have no idea what the cause could be...

Comment: Seeing the output of  " echo | xargs --show-limits" in the shell it seems I have a limit of 4096 in the arguments, maybe it is related to that. Anyway thank you for your help, Matthias.

Comment: That was my original thought, too (cf. my very first comment :))